# How can I move an edge a precise distance from another edge?

Tags: modeling

In the image below, I have an edge loop selected.  I would like to move that edge loop to be exactly 0.30083 from the edge loop on the right.  How can I move it precisely?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the snap to edge tool while in edit mode found on the bottom toolbar of the Viewport. Snap the selected edge to the second one and then use the keys `G` + `y` + `-0.30083` to move it left by the appropriate amount.